# Convert Scala Array[Object] to Map

Tags: scala

I have an array with objects (`Array[Organisation]`). The `Organisation` object contains a `long` orgId and a `string` orgName.

Is there a convenient way of converting this into a `Map[Long, String]` (orgId, orgName)

```
case class OrgRegistryConfig() {

  var organisations: Array[Organisation] = _

  def toMap() : Map[Long, String] = // How??
  // Output: Map( orgId as Long -> orgName as String )

}

object OrgRegistryConfig {
  case class Organisation() {
    var orgId: Long = _
    var orgName: String = _
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`organisations.map { o => o.orgId -> o.orgName }.toMap`

^^ that should do it.

On a related note, don't use `var` unless you know for sure the exact reason why you *must* be using it (95% of cases in scala you don't need it, and it's best to just pretend that keyword does not exist, until you have enough of a grasp of the language to distinguish those rare cases when you do), and *definitely* not in case classes.

Also, don't declare case class members outside of the constructor. And do not create case classes without parameters.

```
case class OrgRegistryConfig(organizations: Array[Organization]) {
  def toMap = organizations.map { o => o.orgId -> o.orgName }.toMap
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I am using Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties, therefor I had to replicate some Java-behavior to make it work. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982686/2291510

Comment: Yeah ... don't use that.

Comment: I can't do it differently as I know. This is a large application written in Scala & Spring Boot. The list needs to be updated in a running cloud solution without re-deploying the application. I can't put this in a database. Having it in a configmap does the work :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most efficient solution:

```
def toMap: Map[Long, String] =
  organisations.map(o => o.orgId -> o.orgName)(collection.breakOut)
```

Using `breakOut` means that the `Map` will be created directly from the `Array`. If you use `toMap` then it will create an intermediate array which is then converted to a `Map`.